# can't allocate custom amount of ram to java when starting process from C#

Tags: c#, java, memory, minecraft

So basically, I'm making a minecraft server wrapper, which I want to execute "java -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar server.jar" but I keep getting errors about the Heap size.
I have tried it with only one of the 2 arguments but that didn't work either. When I run it from a seperate batch file though it always works. (I have 20Gb ram)

I kind of figured that it might be that I'm stuck in my C#'s memory area thing, and that there would probably bee a ProcessStaryInfo variable with which I could get out of that.

Anyways if anyone knew the solution (s)he'd be a great help!

(Forgive spelling/language mistakes, I'm not natively English and wrote this on my phone)

Comment: It's possible that the c# application is 32-bit, in which case it would be launching Java as a 32-bit process, which would involve memory limitations. If this is the case, try compiling for x64...

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem! thanks.

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance. I've upgraded my comment to an answer for future visitors!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your c# application is 32-bit, in which case it would be launching Java as a 32-bit process, which would limit the amount of RAM that Java could address. If this is the case, try recompiling your c# application as x64.

Answer (score 0):

Try launching 64-bit Java. C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/javaw.exe -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar server.jar